# counting specific dictionary entries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dictionary and I want to count the amount of keys that have a specific format.
The keys that I want to count are all the keys that have the format ‘letter, number, number’.
In my specific case the key always begins with the letter ‘A’. only the numbers change.
Example: A12, A16, A71

For example I want to count all the entries that have this AXX format (where the X’s are numbers).

```
{'A34': 83, 'B32': 70, 'A44': 66, A12: 47, 'B90': 71}
```

I know I can count all the entries of my dictionary by using:

```
print(len(my_dict.keys()))
```

but how do I count up all the entries that have the specific format I need.

Comment: You just get the `keys` and do parsing on those keys.  What's your expected output in this case then?

Comment: 1: write a function to test whether a key has the expected format (returning a boolean) and 2: `sum(map(IS_EXPECTED_KEY_FORMAT, d.keys()))`

Comment: How large is your real `my_dict` typically?

Comment: @nocomment apologies, it is about 5000 items.

Comment: @kitchen800 Thanks. How do they look? There are only 2600 obvious possibilities from A00 to Z99. Do you also have items with more than two digits?

Comment: in my case all my A values have 2 digits. However other values that I have such as B and C values will have 3 digits.

Comment: @kitchen800 Alright, thanks. Added a benchmark to my answer now (not that I ever intended for this to be about efficiency, but someone called my solution inefficient (and perhaps was the one who downvoted it for that, as that happened almost at the same time)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator comprehension inside the `sum` function:

```
print(sum(1 for k in d.keys() if k.startswith('A') and len(k) == 3 and k[1:3].isdigit()))
```

This does three checks: if the key starts with A, if the length of this key is 3 and if the last two characters of this key is a digit.

You can also use Regex:

```
import re
print(sum(1 for k in d.keys() if re.match('^A\\d{2}$', k)))
```

Both snippets outputs 3.

Comment: Note that ``k[1:2]`` is a slice of length 1.

Comment: the regex version did exactly what i was trying to do. thanks

Comment: Could this regex version be changed to delete all key value pairs in the dictionary, where the key has that format?

Comment: See benchmark in my updated answer, these are very inefficient (not that I was the one turning this into an efficiency issue, just saying since you did).

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension.

```
len([key for key in list(my_dict.keys()) if 'A' in key])
```

For your specific condition, we can try the below, if you need to be more specific then write a regex in the if clause.

```
len([key for key in list(my_dict.keys()) if ((key.startswith('A')) and (len(key)==3))])
```

Should work!

Comment: it'll print length of dictionary containing A, not the value of A

Comment: That is what was asked, just the count and not for the value.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all possibilities and check?

```
result = sum(f'A{i:02}' in my_dict for i in range(100))
```

Benchmark along with the solutions from the accepted answer, with a dict like you [described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR6F7.png) your real one ("about 5000 items" and "all my A values have 2 digits. However other values that I have such as B and C values will have 3 digits."):

```
  41.5 μs  sum(f'A{i:02}' in my_dict for i in range(100)) 
 573.5 μs  sum(1 for k in my_dict.keys() if k.startswith('A') and len(k) == 3 and k[1:3].isdigit())
3546.0 μs  sum(1 for k in my_dict.keys() if re.match('^A\d{2}$', k))
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJdTsMwDMffcwoLgZJAVdYNEEzqQ5G4BDCmsqXDKumixBOapt2MM3Cl4bTdhgQv5CWx8/fPH4lb09uyGd06v9tVfmmB0BokQOuWnsAbZ0oSIhhaOchBSilamS@bOW@9LJTWvZvuJpDHZrG/KcMMcbpyzvhZGQzb8G6IjA/ikEKIgtFPlSw2OB4MtxKqpQcEbGKahVHZYKAn4n742Mk2HWG7wV7a2VHfs38DEmBIpBQtpStYFXCxPzI9gas71iRwHaXCrqdznBGr45bG5mqzDooJWsRBiIdYjwBeJ2Fl1Y8GOPM@/I9e9ElyjMpaRf0jJG3TaMAK6jRQ6Sl8IL0pWUgNPHfuslG1hjyHUWvXT9l4NEkxzHGBpP7B9ya1Jc2Y/VI8P883w@2pTKBuCRMhYuT0WPtIj1tudJvofujsuJqVfeU3yHnOB1@cncVGdb9ImQTaf5T04rzbtIbL3nOIdPyHSMmzmzSr4OszgIQzUATnkJkbfiGjxVGmd7tv)):

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = '''
from random import sample
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
import re

A = [f'A{i:02}' for i in range(100)]
B2Z = [f'{letter}{i}' for letter in letters for i in range(10, 1000)]
A2Z = sample(A + sample(B2Z, 4900), 5000)
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(A2Z)
'''

E = [
    "sum(f'A{i:02}' in my_dict for i in range(100))",
    "sum(1 for k in my_dict.keys() if k.startswith('A') and len(k) == 3 and k[1:3].isdigit())",
    "sum(1 for k in my_dict.keys() if re.match('^A\\d{2}$', k))",
]

for _ in range(3):
    for e in E:
        number = 10
        t = min(repeat(e, setup, number=number)) / number
        print('%6.1f μs ' % (t * 1e6), e)
    print()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239048/discussion-on-answer-by-no-comment-counting-specific-dictionary-entries-in-pytho).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

my_dict = { ... }
filtered = filter(lambda k: bool(re.match("^[A-Z][0-9]{2}", k)), my_dict.keys())
print(len(filtered))
```